# Can two different OSs share a root partition?

Tags: partitioning, external-hdd, budgie

I have Ubuntu installed on an external HDD and I would like to also install SteamOS and I'm wondering if, when partitioning/installing, they can share the root partition so there's more space for both of them should they need it.

If it *isn't* possible, could someone please explain why?

Thank you!

Comment: Installing another OS to the same partition will overwrite lots of original files, or create double copies. Bad idea, though probably not impossible.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

### Simple Answer

No.

### Explanation

A Unix-type OS (including Ubuntu, or any other Linux-based OS) is defined largely by files that are in fixed locations relative to the root (`/`) directory, such as `/etc/fstab` (which describes the partitions) and key binaries in `/bin` and `/sbin`. Every distribution has its own unique set of files in these locations. (In the case of some files, like `/etc/fstab`, they're customized for a particular installation; but that just means that two OSes that shared the files would require identical settings, which further means they'd be identical and therefore not really two OSes.) These key files are mostly located in directories off of the root (`/`), but they're in directories that may not be mounted from separate filesystems (such as `/etc`, `/bin`, and `/sbin`), so the fact that they're in directories doesn't matter. In a very real sense, the root (`/`) filesystem *is* the OS; it can't be shared. (You can mount one distribution's root directory *elsewhere* in another distribution, but that's not sharing it in the sense I believe you meant.)

### The Technical Way to Worm Out of the Above Answer

Your question asked about a shared "root *partition.*" (Emphasis added.) My answer relates to *directories* (or, by implication, *filesystems*). These need not be exactly equivalent. Most notably, if you use the [Logical Volume Manager (LVM),](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Lvm) multiple filesystems can share a single partition; they'd just be in distinct logical volumes (LVs). Thus, you can install multiple Linux distributions in a single LVM physical volume (PV; that is, partition). I don't think this is what you meant, though; I think you were asking about a shared root (`/`) *filesystem/directory* despite the fact that you used the word *partition.*

### EDIT: An Even Weirder Way To Get It To Work

Another way to get two distributions to share a root (`/`) partition has occurred to me: The Linux kernel runs a program called `init` to handle startup tasks. It's possible to tell the kernel to use another program by passing the `init=` kernel option, as in `init=/foo/bar` to have it run `/foo/bar`. In principle, you could use this option to pass one distribution's kernel a non-standard `init` program that, in turn, looks for support programs in non-standard locations. This approach would require creating an entirely new distribution, or at least modifying some key components -- maybe to install everything it needs in some directory, like `/myweirddistrib`, `/myweirddistrib/etc`, `/myweirddistrib/sbin`, and so on.

Although this *should* work in principle, in practice it would take a lot of work. Many programs include either hard-coded default paths or rely on default paths set in configuration files, and you'd need to modify all of these to get it to work, which means that you would not be able to get an "off-the-shelf" distribution to work; you'd have to create the distribution yourself. You might be able to use a standard distribution as a base, but you'd need to rebuilt many (maybe most or all) packages. Anything that was not modified would end up using the "native" `/`-resident distribution's files, which could result in some weird problems. Thus, this approach is more of a theoretical idea than a practical suggestion.

Comment: You're right; I did mean the root filesystem. Thank you for the explanation! It answered my question perfectly! :)